# Help with repeated measures analysis in a complex design

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I'm looking at a study measuring blood flow in the brain, there are 8 subjects in this study, with 18 measurements each. The measurements are done 6 at a time in three different time points (sessions). Each measurement alternates between control and case, so that in one of the sessions, the six measurements is control, case, control, ..., case (a carryover effect was not accounted for but should be negligible). The sessions take place over two days about a week apart. One day has two sessions in it and a day a week before or after (varies depending on the subject) has the third session. The question being asked (not the question the study was designed for) is if there is a change in the blood flow over time between cases and controls. The difference in blood flow within session, between session same day, and between session different day is of interest. To sum it up, there are 18 measurements of each of the 8 subjects, with each subject having measurements for both case and control condition and in each session.

I have tried to do a repeated measures anova on the data, but am confused on how to set up the model since every subject is crossed with the time and condition factors. Using R, I tried the model

```
aovout = aov(CBF ~ session + condition + session*condition + Error(subject))
```

But think that the error term needs to be changed in order to accommodate for the fact that each subject is in both the control and case group, though I am not sure how to do this.

I'm also unsure if a repeated measures ANOVA is appropriate since there are repeats across subjects and condition and there is an unbalanced number of repeated measurements for the subjects (two subjects only had 12 measurements). I think to try a mixed model next, but am not sure how to set up this model either, as I don't know what to set as the random effect.

Any insight on which analysis might be more appropriate (mixed models or anova) and a push in the right direction in setting up the model would be greatly appreciated!